Facebook recent logins missing from login screen
I have more than one facebook account and when I log out of one, there use to be a section to the left of the login box labeled "Recent logins" with pictures of different facebook accounts who had logged under that browser, so that I could log in by just clicking the picture.
It looks like this:

That section is now not showing up.  How do I get it back?

I wasn’t able to reproduce the profile selection not appearing so make sure you are logged into multiple profiles.

Yes, I am logged into multiple profiles. In the above example, I was logged into 5 profiles, but after having an error creating a new account, the entire recent logins section is now missing from the login page
